# Excel Help : Random Number Generator

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel on the Random Number Generation function, how can I add probabilities to my range of numbers generated? Example : If I have a range from -1 to 2 let's say, how can I tell excel to generate 30% negative and 70% positive numbers?

Comment: Do you need exactly 30% negative numbers and 70% positive? If you have a range from -1 to 2, then a flat distribution gives you 33.33% negative and 66.67% positive numbers which is fairly close.

Comment: What have you tried? Off the top of my head, this will require a UDF/VBA.  How many numbers total do you expect to have? I assume at least 10?  What if you want just two random numbers?

Comment: In your -1 to 2 range, do you expect integer numbers or also fractions?

Answer (score 2):

This will provide you with the distribution you want:

```
=IF(RAND()<=0.3,RANDBETWEEN(-1,0),RANDBETWEEN(0,2))
```

This will provide fractional numbers with the distribution you want:

```
=IF(RAND()<=0.3,-RAND(),2*RAND())
```